# What does DIM do and how would I use it in batch, what other languages should I use?

Tags: windows, basic

I'm programming a basic checkers program from a pdf of very old computer games found [here](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/_Books/101_BASIC_Computer_Games_Mar75.pdf)
[image]
using windows batch, but the program listing calls for DIM What does that do? And other than BASIC what better languages could I use?

Comment: Wow, that's an old one that brings back memories... You can not write it using batch commands, it is all written in Basic. I had the exact same thought ... back in 1979 when I first started out in programming, except I was going to do it on a Data General Nova 4 mini computer.

Comment: You are me, 36 years ago. Did I say that out loud?

Comment: Add a snipped of the listing, please.

Comment: Oh man, I haven't thought about this book in close to a decade. Just out of curiosity, what made you think it was written in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not `batch`, that's a question about `BASIC`.

But to answer it:

`DIM` reserves memory for a variable or an array.

But as SteveFerg already commented, your chances to "translate" a BASIC program to batch are bad. Simple things *can* be done, but it would be a complete rewriting, not just translation. Differences between BASIC (a program language) and Batch (a scripting "language") are too big.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'm new to batch and didn't realize the difference is there any way to code basic on windows 8.1?

Comment: if not are there any other languages I could use?

Comment: you can google for "free basic interpreter" or "free basic compiler". But be aware, there are hundreds of implementations of BASIC (although only a few for free). They may differ a lot in commands and syntax. Don't expect any program (above "hello world") to run without changes. Alternatives? Depends on your needs. Playing? "serious" programming? Game programming? Command line based? GUI? Graphics? ... ....